# Uploadify: start uploading manually

Tags: javascript, file-upload, uploadify

I need to have an ability to start uploading each file in the queue manually, but it doesn't work for me.
That's what I'm trying to do:

```
$('#fileinput').uploadify({
    uploader: 'uploader.php',
    swf: 'uploadify.swf',
    auto: false,
    onSelect: function (file) {
        $('form').append('<br><a href="#" onclick="startUpload(\''+file.id+'\'); return false;">Start uploading '+file.name+' ('+file.id+')</a>');
    }
});         
function startUpload(fileId) {
    $('#fileinput').uploadify('upload', fileId);
}
```

One file is being uploaded well, but while it's being uploaded, other links don't work.
And only after the first file is uploaded, I can start uploading next file.

Debug message is: StartUpload(): Upload already in progress. Not starting another upload.

Is there any way to be able to start uploading while another file is being uploaded?